# Is the use of Unicode characters appropriate when using enum syntax?

Tags: enums, dart

The following results in `unexpected character: '김' (U+AE40)`.  Is unicode not meant for enum elements?

```
enum Banchan {
    김치,
    나물,
    볶음
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Identifiers in Dart can only contain letters, a-z, A-Z, digits 0-9, underscores and dollar signs.

For the gory details see "16.32 Identifier Reference" in the [spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-408.pdf).